# Formatear json en javascript

Tags: javascript, json

recupero de una API extern la siguiente información

```
[{
    "date": "2019-05-14 13:30:00",
    "4_X_X_30_last": 6863,
    "7_X_X_7_last": 6559,
    "11_X_X_600_avg": 361,
    "21_X_X_650_last": 36.906471,
    "22_X_X_651_last": -2.209531,
    "23_X_X_652_last": 139.1,
    "24_X_X_659_last": 0.9,
    "2000_001EC0953E41_X_33798_last": 6196,
    "2001_001EC0953E41_X_33799_last": 9888,
    "2004_001EC095ADBE_X_34049_avg": 379,
    "2004_001EC095ADBE_X_34049_max": 384,
    "2004_001EC095ADBE_X_34049_min": 375
}]
```

Necesito convertir esta JSON a un tipo determinado.

En primer lugar el Date tiene que estar dentro de metadata --> timestamp-->value.
No se como al crear el nuevo JSON omitir que aparezca en la primera posición y que pinte ese dato en el resto en el lugar indicado arriba.

Este es el resultado deseado:

```
{
    "4_X_X_30_last": {
        "type": "float",
        "value": 6863,
        "metadata": {
            "timestamp": {
                "type": "String",
                "value": "2019-05-14 13:30:00"
            }
        }
    },
    "7_X_X_7_last": {
        "type": "float",
        "value": 6559,
        "metadata": {
            "timestamp": {
                "type": "String",
                "value": "2019-05-14 13:30:00"
            }
        }
    },
    "11_X_X_600_avg": {
        "type": "float",
        "value": 361,
        "metadata": {
            "timestamp": {
                "type": "String",
                "value": "2019-05-14 13:30:00"
            }
        }
    },
    "21_X_X_650_last": {
        "type": "float",
        "value": 36.906471,
        "metadata": {
            "timestamp": {
                "type": "String",
                "value": "2019-05-14 13:30:00"
            }
        }
    },
    "22_X_X_651_last": {
        "type": "float",
        "value": -2.209531,
        "metadata": {
            "timestamp": {
                "type": "String",
                "value": "2019-05-14 13:30:00"
            }
        }
    },
    "23_X_X_652_last": {
        "type": "float",
        "value": 139.1,
        "metadata": {
            "timestamp": {
                "type": "String",
                "value": "2019-05-14 13:30:00"
            }
        }
    },
    "24_X_X_659_last": {
        "type": "float",
        "value": 0.9,
        "metadata": {
            "timestamp": {
                "type": "String",
                "value": "2019-05-14 13:30:00"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Por otro lado cómo podía transformar esa fecha que contiene Date a un formato UNIX?.

Este es el codigo que estoy probando:

```js
var pruebas = [{ "date": "2019-05-14 13:30:00", "4_X_X_30_last": 6863, "7_X_X_7_last": 6559, "11_X_X_600_avg": 361, "21_X_X_650_last": 36.906471, "22_X_X_651_last": -2.209531, "23_X_X_652_last": 139.1, "24_X_X_659_last": 0.9, "2000_001EC0953E41_X_33798_last": 6196, "2001_001EC0953E41_X_33799_last": 9888, "2004_001EC095ADBE_X_34049_avg": 379, "2004_001EC095ADBE_X_34049_max": 384, "2004_001EC095ADBE_X_34049_min": 375 }];


var key = Object.keys(pruebas)[0];

    var finalobj = {};
    for (var e in pruebas[key]) {
        entidad: finalobj[e] = {
            type: "float",
            value: parseFloat(pruebas[key][e]),
            metadata: {
                timestamp: {
                    type: "String",
                    value: pruebas[key][e]
                }
            }
        };
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(finalobj,null,2));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con esta función puedes hacer las dos cosas que planteas en tu pregunta

```
// Creo la funcion que devuelve el nuevo json con la estructura deseada, pasandole
// el json como parámetro
let formatearJSON = function(json) {
 // Arreglo con los cambios del json
 const array = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json)).map(function(element, index) {
     // Obtengo la fecha a setear en el metadata > timestamp > value
     const date = element.date;
     // Convierto a Unix format la fecha y le quito los milisegundos (no son necesarios), si quieres dejarlos omite la parte .toString().split().....
     const unixDate = (new Date(date).getTime()/1000).toString().split('.')[0];
     //Remuevo la propiedad de la fecha donde estaba originalmente para posicionarla
     // en un nuevo lugar posteriormente
     delete element.date;
     // Recorro las llaves del elemento actual de la iteracion del arreglo del json
     for(var key in element){
        // Creo la nueva estructura
        element[key] = {
            type: isNaN(element[key]) ? 'String' : 'float',
              value: isNaN(element[key]) ? element[key] : parseFloat(element[key]),
              metadata: {
                 timestamp: {
                     type: 'String',
                     value: unixDate //Fecha ya convertida a formato UNIX
                 }
              }
        };
     }
     return element; 
 });

 return array;
};

const json = [{"date":"2019-05-14 13:30:00","4_X_X_30_last":6863,"7_X_X_7_last":6559,"11_X_X_600_avg":361,"21_X_X_650_last":36.906471,"22_X_X_651_last":-2.209531,"23_X_X_652_last":139.1,"24_X_X_659_last":0.9,"2000_001EC0953E41_X_33798_last":6196,"2001_001EC0953E41_X_33799_last":9888,"2004_001EC095ADBE_X_34049_avg":379,"2004_001EC095ADBE_X_34049_max":384,"2004_001EC095ADBE_X_34049_min":375}];
// Con esto puedes comprobar que devuelve el formato correcto el nuevo json
console.log(formatJSON(json));
```

Puedes verificar el valor si es correcto el de la fecha en esta url: https://www.epochconverter.com/

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93770/discussion-on-answer-by-dariel-ramos-diaz-de-villegas-formatear-json-en-javascri).

Comment: @Manolait recuerda aceptar la respuesta si sirvio. Y si no sirvio, aclara porque.